# IOS and Objective C - How to display an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries in NSUserDefaults in Tableview?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

Basically I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries stored to NSUserDefaults.

I have implemented tableview into my app but I am not sure how to display the individual values. I know that I am not providing much information (such as the keys I used) but could anyone give me a basic example on how access the values stored in NSDictionaries?

The code below doesn't work obviously, but if it were just a string it would be accessible in this way:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"parked locations"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored mutable arrays in, you can access the `NSMutableArray` with the key `@"parked locations"` :

```
NSMutableArray *parkedLocations = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                   objectForKey:@"parked locations"];
```

Each element of that array is a `NSDictionary` you access like that :

```
NSDictionary *parkedLocation = [parkedLocations objectAtIndex:0]; // the first
```

Finally inside each dictionary, access values like, for example `NSString` :

```
NSString *locationName = [parkedLocation objectForKey:@"theKeyForTheName"];
```

As `NSUserDefaults` can store objects of type : `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`, yes, if it were just a string, you could access it like you wrote.

You will find more information in [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i) and [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

Comment: Thank you so much, that is very very helpful. Will accept when it lets me

Comment: @TaylorMac : you are welcome. Keep in mind `NSUserDefaults` isn't parent related with `NSDictionary` or its mutable form, but it only works the same way, except with a dictionaray keys are typed `id`.

Comment: Hey Taylor could you please post your method for creating the NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries in NSUserDefaults? It would help me out soooo much if you could!